# influxdb cli how to use string literals

Tags: shell, influxdb

I want to do a query using influxdb command line tool. Can I use string literal in provided query?

example:

`influx -username '...' -password '...' -execute 'SELECT last("point") AS "point", time FROM ... GROUP BY time(1d) FILL(previous) tz('Asia/Tehran')'`

I can not use time zone 'Asia/Tehran' string literal in it.

PS: I have tried `tz(\'Asia/Tehran\')` and `tz("Asia/Tehran")` too, but none of them worked properly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what are the error messages..?

Comment: `tz('Asia/Tehran')` and `tz("Asia/Tehran")` causes `expected string argument in tz()` error.
`tz(\'Asia/Tehran\')` causes `syntax error near unexpected token \`)'` error.

Comment: seems like `syntax` error.. may i see the full query?or only `GROUP BY` clause. .what is your objective ..? do you want to `group by` `time zone` ?

Comment: No there is no syntax error. When i run query inside influx shell it works. The problem is single quote inside query which we must pass it within two single quotes by execute parameter.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed problem using double quotes in execute argument and escape query `"` with `\"`.

`influx -username '...' -password '...' -execute "SELECT last(\"point\") AS \"point\", time FROM ... GROUP BY time(1d) FILL(previous) tz('Asia/Tehran')"`